# javascript - ES6 array function to create an object from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

i'd like to make this array:

```
[
  { 
    event: "LIB",
    block_calendar: "YES",
    obs: "Lorem Ipsum",
    status: "Block",
  },
  { 
    event: "LIB"
    block_calendar: "YES"
    obs: "Ipsum Lorem"
    status: "Block"
  }
]
```

turn into this object

```
{
  event: "LIB",
  obs: ["Lorem Ipsum","Ipsum Lorem"]
}
```

How can I accomplish this result using ES6?

Comment: This is  fairly standard "groupBy" operation. If you haven't alreaady done so try researching that term. If you have already made attempts to solve this but it's not working as expected then show us that code. The objective here is to help you with your code, not do all the work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate an object with the desired data. Foreach object from your array look if the accumultaed object has an entry for the lib-key (i.e. it's not undefined). If not create it with the property event and obs (with an empty array as start). In both cases add to this array your obs-value.
To get the desired array out of this use [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get rid of the outer grouping-event.
**Note**: I generalized your problem a little bit, so that you can have different events that will be grouped.

```js
let arr = [
  { 
    event: "LIB",
    block_calendar: "YES",
    obs: "Lorem Ipsum",
    status: "Block",
  },
  { 
    event: "LIB",
    block_calendar: "YES",
    obs: "Ipsum Lorem",
    status: "Block"
  }
];

let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc[cur.event]) 
        acc[cur.event] = {event: cur.event, obs: []};
    acc[cur.event].obs.push(cur.obs);
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```